# Parse json array without value in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I wonder how to parse a json array without values

```
Json: {"status":"FAILED","errors":{"email":["NOT_UNIQUE"],"name":["TOO_SHORT"]}}
```

How can i get the value of email in a foreach loop?

What i mean with "without value" is: there is an array called email and name... How can i get the value for "email" that currently says NOT_UNIQUE?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Did you try json_decode ?

Comment: "Without values"? What does that mean? What have you tried? `json_decode` the JSON and then handle it like any other array...!?

Comment: your current json string in your example is not valid, therefore, you cannot get the values. maybe a typo in your part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current example, your JSON string is malformed. I dont know if thats a typo on your part while creating your question. Assuming the JSON string is okay in your code, a simple `json_decode()` will do just fine. Consider this example:

```
$json_string = '{ "Json": { "status": "FAILED", "errors": { "email": [ "NOT_UNIQUE" ], "name": [ "TOO_SHORT" ] } }}';
$data = json_decode($json_string, true);
echo $data['Json']['errors']['email'][0]; // NOT UNIQUE
```

Answer (score 0):

use `json_decode`, `json_decode($str, true)` will return it as an assosiative array whereas json_decode($str, false) will return objects.

json_decode("{"status":"FAILED","errors":{"email":["NOT_UNIQUE"],"name":["TOO_SHORT"]}}", true)['errors']['email']

should get the email for you.

Comment: I know how to to that, but how can i get the value of email i tried $json->errors->email but it will not work.